# Chunking a large file into pieces for pairwise processing entries and recombining intermediate results afterwards

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have a large text file (several gigs) that contain several hundred thousand entries. I need to process these pairwise, and generate something like a correlation matrix, except it's not the correlation but a custom function I am applying. I already have a method that takes a small file (n=500) and calculates a matrix within a few seconds. I have modified this function to accept two collections, instead of one, and calculates from i-> j, instead of i-> i

So in order to do this in the most efficient way possible, I want to chunk the input file and use multiple cores. My current approach is as follows:

1. Get chunks out of the reader, using `grouper()` which is from [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)
2. Use `itertools.product()` to get pairs of indices (i, j) to get chunk pairs
3. call `pool.starmap()` to get intermediate results

See below:

```
def chunk_file(reader):
    def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
        yield from itertools.zip_longest(*[iter(iterable)] * n, fillvalue=fillvalue)

    chunks = [chunk for chunk in grouper(reader, 1000)]

    chunk_pairs = [(chunks[i], chunks[j]) for i, j in itertools.product(range(len(chunks), len(chunks))) if i > j]
    with multiprocessing.Pool(args.nthreads) as pool:
        frames = pool.starmap(process_asym, chunk_pairs)
        return frames
```

This is not necessarily a good solution however since:

I. This is not a good use of `grouper()`, I think all the benefits from working with iterators is gone here since I put them in a list comprehension. It would have been better if I could only work with iterators, in order to avoid reading the entire file to memory. I am not sure how to do that though...

II. I am not sure if my approach of getting the pairs is particularly smart, maybe I should just pass indices, but how would one go about doing that? The downstream code (i.e. `process_asym`) is the bit which extracts the relevant information from entries (e.g. chunk1 & chunk2) and calls a highly streamlined function which calculates the end result for a pair of entries (e.g chunk1_i & chunk2_j).

III. Reconstructing the matrix from individual subframes isn't entirely trivial either.

I feel like there must be a smarter approach here, since this should be a fairly common problem with the ever-growing datasets.

Comment: By a text file, do you mean a tab delimited file?

Comment: @d_kennetz nope, it's a custom file format used for research, it's a plain text file though